# Laravel custom serviceprovider for validator

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, service-provider

I want to override a method (`isValidatable`) in the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` class. I have done this by creating a class (outside Illuminate) that extends the Validator and only overrides the `isValidatable` method.

I think this will work, except I'm not sure how to create the service provider for the Validator class (or actually `CustomLaravelValidator` class). I have created service providers before, but there seems to be going on a lot inside the Validator serviceprovider (`Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider`). Therefore I don't have a clue on how my custom service provider for this class should look like.

This is my CustomLaravelValidator class:

```
<?php namespace API\Extensions\Core;

use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomLaravelValidator extends Validator {

    /**
     * Determine if the attribute is validatable.
     *
     * @param  string  $rule
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed   $value
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isValidatable($rule, $attribute, $value)
    {
        // Validate integers on empty strings as well
        if($rule == 'IntStrict')
        {
            return true;
        }
        return $this->presentOrRuleIsImplicit($rule, $attribute, $value) &&
        $this->passesOptionalCheck($attribute);
    }

}
```

This is the default ValidationServiceProvider from Laravel:

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Validation;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerPresenceVerifier();

        $this->app->bindShared('validator', function($app)
        {
            $validator = new Factory($app['translator'], $app);

            // The validation presence verifier is responsible for determining the existence
            // of values in a given data collection, typically a relational database or
            // other persistent data stores. And it is used to check for uniqueness.
            if (isset($app['validation.presence']))
            {
                $validator->setPresenceVerifier($app['validation.presence']);
            }

            return $validator;
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the database presence verifier.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerPresenceVerifier()
    {
        $this->app->bindShared('validation.presence', function($app)
        {
            return new DatabasePresenceVerifier($app['db']);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return array('validator', 'validation.presence');
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me how my custom serviceprovider have to look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your service provider doesn't need to mimic the native Validator service provider. You just need to register your custom validator using the `resolver` method on the validator factory.

```
use API\Extensions\Core\CustomLaravelValidator;

class CustomValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->app['validator']
             ->resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
        {
            return new CustomLaravelValidator(
                $translator, 
                $data, 
                $rules, 
                $messages
            );
        });
    }
}
```

That's it...

Comment: For anyone wandering in here a few years later: the current method is to extend the Validator facade with `Validator::extend`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#using-extensions